# How can I connected to Mysql database using JSP? where I'm wrong in my code?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

How can I get connected jsp to mysql. Where I'm wrong? My index.jsp page working correctly. But I, doubt about <%@include file="DB conn"%> what is should be written in form action and my DB conn.jsp file has real error.

How can I remove error from this code using jsp.What is error in it?
Your suggestion is important for me, thanks.

**db conn.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
 <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
    <%
     Connection c1 = null;
     Statement st = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     c1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher","root", "abcde");
        {
         System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
         System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
      System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

      st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
          System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
             {
          System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");  
           se.printStackTrace();}    //Stack Trace Added
           if (c1!= null) {
               System. out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("We should never get here.");
            }}
            %>
              <%
       try{

        String name=request.getParameter("username");
        String abc=request.getParameter("password");       
        String Sql="select * from login where username='"+name+"' AND password='"+abc+"'";
        ResultSet rs=c1.st.executeQuery(Sql);   //error line
      while(rs.next())  {
      out.println("aa");}
       catch(SQLException ex)
         {
         out.println(ex);
         }
         %>
```

---

**index.jsp**

```
      <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <%@include file="db conn.jsp" %>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form  method="GET " action="reg.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
      <h1>Log in</h1> 
        <p> 
     <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Username:</label>
     <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password:</label>
     <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
     </p>
     <p class="keeplogin"> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
     <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
     </p>
     <p class="login button"> 
     <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
     <input type="button" onclick="location.href='reg.jsp';" value="Sign Up"/>
     </p>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Teach" checked/> Teacher
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student
     </form> 
     </body>
 </html>
```

**error**

```
    HTTP Status 500 -
    type Exception report

    message

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /db conn.jsp:62

    62:             while(rs.next())  {}
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace.

Comment: `se.printStackTrace();` You can see it in code my moving down

Comment: Show the **output** of the stacktrace. You know, the text it printed to your console.

Comment: `init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8081/project
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8081/project
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8081/project
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)`

Comment: Why do you not try to correct my code of db conn.jsp only

Comment: Can't correct if I don't know the problem. I don't know the problem without seeing the error logs.

Comment: Also, what you posted is not stacktrace output.

Comment: I think the is a  issue here is that you are connecting to the database in the JSP.   Do you have the option to have better separation of concerns?   It worries me the number of connections you would make to the DB if this site was busy and how slow that might be. It would be more usual in this case to have some servlet which responds to the request, calls a service class to do the required database processing (making use of a connection pool), add the result to the session / request and then delegate to the JSP To answer the question properly we do need to see the full error on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please include try and catch block in db conn.jsp? It may solve you issue.